# How to run Python powered CLI like a normal system CLI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface

I want to run my built CLI like other cli tools, for eg, `kubectl`, `redis`, etc. Currently, I run my cli as: `python3 cli.py subarg --args`; instead, I want to run: `invdb subarg --args` where invdb is the Python package.

The structure of the project repository is:

```
.
├── CHALLENGE.md
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── README.md
├── __pycache__
│   └── config.cpython-38.pyc
├── data_platform_challenge_darwin
├── data_platform_challenge_linux
├── data_platform_challenge_windows
├── discussion_answers_rough_work
├── dist
│   ├── invdb-0.0.1.tar.gz
│   └── invdb-tesla-kebab-mai-haddi-0.0.1.tar.gz
├── example.json
├── invdb
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── analysis.py
│   ├── cleanup.py
│   ├── cli.py
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── etl.py
│   ├── groups.py
│   ├── initialize_db.py
│   └── nodes.py
├── invdb.egg-info
│   ├── PKG-INFO
│   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   └── top_level.txt
├── setup.py
├── test.db
└── tests
```

Comment: Python is an interpreted language, and you're talking about having an executable on the PATH. There are ways to do this (entrypoint shims through setuptools, mostly). Check out [the v1 aws cli](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli) for an example.

Comment: >Python is an interpreted language, and you're talking about having an executable on the PATH.
Even though there are ways, is what I am asking a good thing to have or `python3 cli.py ...` is the better way?

Comment: I wrote an answer that should help. The advantage is the ease of use. The disadvantage is that you must install it. I produced a complex Python package for internal use at my company which uses this entry_point shim technique, but it required some infrastructure to become useful (we had to stand up a PyPI server, hook up CI/CD, teach all the developer machines how to find the internal PyPI, convince developers to do the `pip install` rather than just syncing and running from source, etc...). That's not to say those drawbacks are _necessary_, just that they're possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setuptools (or is it distutils? The line is so blurry) provides an entry_points.console_scripts option that can do this for you when installing your package. I will provide an example repository at the bottom of my summary.

Construct a project tree like so:

```py
# /mypackage/mymodule.py
print("We did it!")
```

```
# /pyproject.toml
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
# this is required for Python to recognize setuptools as the build backend
```

```
[metadata]
name = sample_module
version = 0.0.1
author = Adam Smith
description = console_script example

[bdist_wheel]
universal = true

[options]
packages = my_package
python_requires = >=2.7
entry_points = 
    [console_scripts]
    sample_module = my_package.my_module:main
```

then run the following at the shell:

```sh
$ python3 -mpip install .
(ed. this will install the file locally. To build a wheel (to install elsewhere) try pep517)
```

If you get a warning about the installation script not being on your PATH, you should consider adding it. Otherwise, just run your new script

```sh
$ sample_module
We did it!
```

GitLab: [nottheeconomist/console_script_example](https://gitlab.com/nottheeconomist/console_script_example)

---

Since you already have a setup.py, consider adding the following entry to your `setuptools.setup` call:

```py
# ...

setuptools.setup(
    # ...
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': ['sample_module=my_package.my_module:main']
    }
)
```